# Validate checkboxes in MVC form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a table in an ASP.NET MVC2 form. On each row in the table there is a checkbox.
Underneath the table there is a submitbutton.

I want to make the button disabled when NONE of the checkboxes are selected.

```
<% using Html.BeginForm(....) { %>
<table>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr> <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedContacts" />
    </td></tr>
<% } //End foreach %> 
</table>
<% } //End using %> 

<input type="submit" value="Create selection" name="CreateSelectionAction" />
```

The number of lines/checkboxes will vary from 1 to many.

How can I use MVC2/jQuery to require the user to selected minimum one checkbox before clicking Submit button?

**Edit**; Of the three answers below I couldn't get any of them to work. Nothing happens when clicking the checkboxes, and no Javascript errors are raised. Setting up a small bounty.

**EDIT2**; Here is what I ended up with.
I gave the form the name createSelectionForm, and used this jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#createSelectionForm, input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            if ($('#createSelectionForm, input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
                $('input[name="CreateSelectionAction"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('input[name="CreateSelectionAction"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hey, I fixed my answer, since the last time I missread your question and wrote total BS. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form-id input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      if ($('#form-id input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
        $('input[name="CreateSelectionAction"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $('input[name="CreateSelectionAction"]').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This was too written from memory. I didn't try it.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting these to work. I added an alert("") in the beginning of the function, and I see it is called when the page is loaded, but nothing happens when I click on the checkboxes. The button is never disabled.

Comment: Got it working - I didn't notice that "form-id" had to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

This basically does:

- Add a handler to the selectboxes
- In the handler, check how many are selected
- If `0` then disable the button
- If `!0` then enable the button

---

```
$('input[name="selectedContacts"]').click(function() {
    var $button = $('input#CreateSelectionAction');
    if($('input[name="selectedContacts"]:checked').length === 0) {
         $button.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
         $button.attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I am sorry that my answer was totally wrong, I did the opposite thing of what you wanted. Here is the fixed version.

When the DOM is ready it will check all checkboxes in your table. If at least one of them is selected it will disable the submit button. When you click one of the checkboxes it will enable it again and if you will de-check it, it will check the other checkboxes as well and if none of them is selected it will disable it.

```
$.checker = function() {
    $('table input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input[name="CreateSelectionAction"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }                   
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.checker();

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input[name="CreateSelectionAction"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $.checker();
        }
    });             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Checkbox Demo</title>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h1>Checkbox Demo</h1>
            Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" class="validatecheckbox" /><br />
            Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" class="validatecheckbox" /><br />
            Checkbox 3: <input type="checkbox" class="validatecheckbox" /><br />
            Checkbox 4: <input type="checkbox" class="validatecheckbox" /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Create selection" id="createselection" />
        </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(Initialize);

        function Initialize() {
            $(".validatecheckbox").change(Validate);
            Validate();
        };

        function Validate() {
            var valid = false;

            valid = $(".validatecheckbox:checked").length > 0;

            if (!valid) {
                $("#createselection").attr("disabled", true);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#createselection").attr("disabled", false);
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

    $('table input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($('table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})();
```